# How to configure In-App Rich Media ad creative in DFP?

Tags: google-dfp, in-app, mraid

I created a html for In-App Rich Media ad for expandable banner. It contains 2 Image files and .js and .css file. How to configure and upload files and create a creative in DFP it will show my apps.

I need some link to configure my own custom MRAID creative in DFP.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create separate server on which you can upload related .js and .css files.

For creative you have to write one sampleCreative.js file in that you can add your html content using document.write() function.

Upload below code as a creative in DFP which will call your sampleCreative.js.

`<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://localserver/sampleCreative.js\"></script>`